# How to fix “Unfortunately Contacts Has Stopped” or Very slow contact loading

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I have Huawei Honor 3c. Android v4.4. When I open my contacts list I get the Headers but no content. It may take 4-10 minutes before this refreshes. Once I get the list selecting an individual contact repeats the delay. In some cases once I get the contact selecting "dial" repeats the process yet again.And many times i'm getting the error `Unfortunately Contacts has stopped working`

I've been selectively uninstalling apps to see if one of these has caused the problem. Previously when I had this issue the only advice huawei could give me was to reset my phone to factory defaults. This worked but then the pain returns once system updates occur and apps are installed. Any suggestions? Are there any tools available the show CPU and/or memory utilization so I can see who the hogs are? This might give me a better indication of which processes are sucking up all the resources.

Comment: First thing I'd try is to lookup that app in *Settings › Apps* and push the "clear cache" button. No data lost that way, but often it's some "broken cache" causing issues like that.

Comment: The Running Apps option under *Settings > Apps* is probably what will tell you who are the greatest resource hogs.

Answer (score 1):

This is very likely to be caused by a bug in an update, but check with other people who have the same phone to be sure. Assuming you want to keep your system updated, I suggest you move to another contacts app like [Contacts+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.contapps.android&hl=en), which offer more options than the stock contacts app.
You might use [CleanMaster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.mguard&hl=en) to see which apps are causing the phone to go slow.
Meanwhile, I would suggest contacting Huawei (if you haven't done so already) so they will fix this issue in a later update.

Answer (score 0):

I constantly had this happening. I tried all suggestions. The problem seemed to be with the stock phone app., as when I downloaded the Truephone app from Playstore it by-passed the 'contacts stopped' window and it works perfectly. So try downloading Truephone.

Comment: Although your suggestion may solve the issue, better you also provide the link to the app that you mentioned in your Answer so that OP or others can install and try it out!

Answer (score 0):

In "Contacts Storage" internal app, I uninstalled updates and now it works fine. Remember to take a backup of all your contacts before doing so, as it would erase its internal database (cache).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I uninstalled the true caller app then it started working properly.